# Flask 404 Url not found

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask server like:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/')
def server_index():
    return app.send_static_file('ngrok_run_a_public_server.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have it in a folder like:

```
examples
  -ngrok_run_a_public_server.html
  -server.py
```

They are both in the same folder, and this is how I saw other people serve static files. I am getting `404` both locally and on ngrok. I just want to server a file publicly.

It fails using both http://127.0.0.1:5000/ and http://127.0.0.1:5000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a folder named `static` inside the examples folder and move your html file in there. It should work then.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a folder in the root directory, any name you want - let's say '*myDailyReports*'. And the file in this folder be say '*Day1.xlsx*'.

```
import os
from flask import send_from_directory, current_app

@app.route('/')
def server_index():    

    path = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'myDailyReports')
    filename = 'Day1.xlsx'

    # returns the file to download as an attachment with as_attachment as True
    return send_from_directory(directory=path, filename=filename, as_attachment=True)
```

If you do not want to download, but just want to display the file contents on the browser, maybe a `.txt` or `.html` file -

```
return send_from_directory(directory=path, filename=filename)
```

Comment: why didnt it work though if I set `static_url_path=''`?